# Is there a way to recognize weather the input to Bot is from microphone or is text input?

Tags: web-chat

In my BOT I want to log the times when speech input was provided to the BOT. Is there a way to recognize it in my BOT Framework solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user speaks to a bot in Web Chat, the generated activity sent to the bot will include a `channelData.speech` property. You can use this as a marker for determining, in the bot, if the activity came from spoken or text input. The `speech` property is not appended when the activity is generated from text input. This applies to both Cognitive Services speech (channelId: 'directline') and Direct Line Speech (channelId: 'directlinespeech').

**Example activity**

```js
  {
    type: 'message',
    id: '26WpGqt6CCz7M8uRN0ugo9-o|0000002',
    timestamp: 2021-01-28T23:12:10.281Z,
    serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
    channelId: 'directline',
    from: { id: '<<REDACTED>>', name: '', role: 'user' },
    conversation: { id: '26WpGqt6CCz7M8uRN0ugo9-o' },
    recipient: { id: '<<REDACTED>>', name: '<<REDACTED>>' },    
    textFormat: 'plain',
    locale: 'en-US',
    text: 'Hello.',
    entities: [ [Object] ],
    channelData: {
      speech: {
        alternatives: [
          {
            confidence: 0.51567326,
            transcript: 'Hello.'
          }
        ]
      },
      clientActivityID: '1611875530186v9cv78togd',
      clientTimestamp: '2021-01-28T23:12:10.186Z'
    },
    rawTimestamp: '2021-01-28T23:12:10.2819155Z',
    callerId: 'urn:botframework:azure'
  }
```

Hope of help!